# How to predict binary outcome from a glmm model

Tags: r, mixed-model, prediction

Suppose I fit a generalized mixed logistic model such like that:

```
set.seed(2014)
require(lme4)
df<-data.frame(id=rep(1:5, c(8,10,12,14,15)), 
               out=c(rbinom(8,1,0.1), rbinom(10,1,0.3),rbinom(12,1,0.1),rbinom(14,1,0.05),rbinom(15,1,0.1)),
               age=rnorm(59,50,10),
               gender=rbinom(59,1,0.5))
fit<-glmer(out~age+gender+(1|id),data=df,binomial)
df$predicted<-predict(fit,type="response")
df$pred.binary<-with(df,ifelse(predicted>=0.5,1,0))
apply(df[,c(2,6)],2,sum)
        out pred.binary 
          9           0
```

What's the best way to predict a binary outcomes by accounting the random effects and with an optimized threshold based on the original data set?

Comment: start with `predict` (i.e. `?predict.merMod`) with `type="response"` to get probabilities, and then tell us more about your definition of an optimal threshold ...

Comment: From my updated demo, you may see, if I use 0.5 as a critical value, the predicted cases will be zero comparing to the 9 cases in the observed out. I got same situation with my real dataset with 25,00 rows and predicted zero case too. Thus I'd think it's necessary to find an optimal threshold.

Comment: to find an optimal threshold you need to know your loss function....

Answer (score 1):

Well, i believe a common practice is to use a threshold of `p=0.5` for the predicted response  which is in `]0 1[`. Not sure how you can optimize this threshold? (I assume `gender` and `age` are between-subjects effects)

EDIT: I see. I would say the problem here is not in the threshold, but in the data/model: the overall chance of `out==1` is low and the predictors of the model don't tell you much about the outcome. Hence, the prediction is `out==0` for all data because, overall, this is the most probable case.

Comment: See my updated demo and the comment above.

Comment: might be worth adding that threshold of 0.5 implies a loss function of 1:1

Answer (score 0):

Two options for predicting binary outcome:

```
1. yhat<-rbinom(nrow(df), 1, predicted)
2. u<-runif(nrow(df))
    yhat<-ifelse(predicted>=u, 1, 0)
```